# format JSON output with excel (cv) headers

Tags: php, json, excel

The below php takes my csv file and outputs to JSON file.

```
<?php

    echo "<h2>Uploading....</h2>";

    $fh = fopen("assets/files/locationsCSV.csv", "r");

    $csvData = array();

    while (($row = fgetcsv($fh, 0, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $csvData[] = $row;
    }
    // echo json_encode($csvData);
    file_put_contents("assets/files/locationsCSV.json",json_encode($csvData))      

?>
```

the JSON in my json file outputs like this, below: **Current Output:**

```
["Zipcode","City","Primary State","SS","County"], # only prints once
["24553","","Virginia","49050","Appomattox"], # then just this 
["24553","","Virginia","49140","Buckingham"], # etc
```

How could I get it to output like this/reformatted with zipcode column as object header?

**Desired JSON output:**

```
{ 
 ZipCode: 24553, { 
 City: , 
 Primary State: Virginia, 
 SS: 49050,
 County: Appomattox
}
```

Comment: Is the trailing "{" in `ZipCode: 24553, { ` a typo? Because it's not valid JSON :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the first row of your CSV file into a keys array, and the combine those keys with each row of data in your loop:

```
$csvData = array();
$keys = fgetcsv($fh, 0, ",");
while (($row = fgetcsv($fh, 0, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $csvData[] = array_combine($keys, $row);
}
```